# Resolving Header File Issues in WSL Ubuntu for a VS2022 CMake Project

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2022

## Header File Include Issue in WSL Ubuntu with VS2022 and CMake

### Problem

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and when I try to include `"GLFW/glfw3.h"` on WSL Ubuntu, I get an error that the source file doesn't exist. However, the same code works perfectly on Windows. (it's a problem with all other libs too but I just took glfw as an example)

### Current Code

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("test project")

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
    glfw
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
    GIT_TAG 3.3.8
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(glfw)
if(NOT glfw_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(glfw)

    set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF)
    set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
    set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF)
    set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF)

    add_subdirectory(${glfw_SOURCE_DIR} ${glfw_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

add_executable(test_exe "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(test_exe PRIVATE glfw)
```

I found a workaround where I would change `FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR` to the project's source directory but it introduced more problems. For example, switching between Windows and WSL Ubuntu requires deleting the fetched files from Windows, or it results in the error :

```
The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/olli/.vs/Omerta/external/glfw/glfw-subbuild/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory c:/Users/Olli/source/repos/GitOlli/Omerta/external/glfw/glfw-subbuild where CMakeCache.txt was created.
```

I have also tried explicitly specifying the include directory but it also doesn't work.

```
target_include_directories(test_exe PRIVATE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/glfw-src/include")
```

Comment: Run building with additional option `VERBOSE=1`. That way it will print the command line which is executed. Then add to the question post this command line and everything after it (It is known as the **complete** error message).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the "out" and ".vs" folders, replace `CMakePresets.json` with `CMakeSettings.json`, and then restart the computer.

[image]